# Kivy app crash on the start, maybe for the requirements

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I’m trying to compile the first version of my app with buildozer, but I don’t know why it crashes. Below the beginning of the main.py and the . spec
(The folder is structured with a .py file, many .kv, and a assets subfolder with all .png files)

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
import kivy
from kivy.animation import Animation
from firebase import firebase
import json
import os
import random
import smtplib
import pyrebase
```

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = app
# (str) Package name
package.name = app

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==master,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,firebase,certifi,charset-normalizer,Cython,docutils,firebase,gcloud,googleapis-common-protos,httplib2,idna,jws,Kivy-Garden,oauth2client,osxrelocator,Pillow,protobuf,pyasn1,pyasn1-modules,pycryptodome,Pygments,pyparsing,Pyrebase,python-jwt,requests,requests-toolbelt,rsa,six,urllib3,wheel



...
```

I am not very experienced in buildozer, as a result I failed to fix it in any way

Answer (score 0):

Post your full buildozer.spec file, also
In your requirements, kivy== shouldn’t be master, you need to specify the kivy version that you want to use, for example, kivy== 2.1.0, the master branch needs to be specified somewhere else in the buildozer.spec file

Answer (score 0):

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = MSP PEMF

# (str) Package name
package.name = MSP_PEMF

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.msppemf

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/assets/images/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/assets/images/logo.png

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
android.presplash_color = #26a69a

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py, gif, png, jpg, jpeg, ttf, kv, json, txt, md

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
# android.enable_androidx = True

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 0.0.109

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy==master, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.archs = arm64-v8a

# android.release_artifact = apk

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
# p4a.branch = develop

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 0
```

I tested over and over with simpler examples to get stable code that worked with buldozer before starting my project.  I used some of the default KivyMD code samples and got them working first.  Then started working on code for my project.

I have since created several stable apps.

RAH